# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-0.‎086167157"

Tags: android, double, numberformatexception

So I have been struggling with this for a while and for me I see no reason why -0.‎086167157 would not be a valid double. I am simply trying to cast a string value that comes back from an API call to a double (longitude value)

Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-0.‎086167157"
W/System.err:     at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextDouble(JsonReader.java:909)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson$2.read(Gson.java:284)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson$2.read(Gson.java:278)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

/

```
@Parcel(implementations = { LocationRealmProxy.class },
    value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
    analyze = {Location.class})
public class Location extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
int locationId;

@SerializedName("company_id")
int companyId;

@SerializedName("company_name")
String companyName;

@SerializedName("logo")
String logo;

@SerializedName("address_one")
String addressOne;

@SerializedName("address_two")
String addressTwo;

@SerializedName("address_three")
String addressThree;

@SerializedName("town")
String town;

@SerializedName("county")
String county;

@SerializedName("postcode")
String postcode;

@SerializedName("country")
String country;

@SerializedName("latitude")
Double latitude;

@SerializedName("longitude")
Double longitude;

@SerializedName("venue_type")
String venueType;

@SerializedName("type")
String type;

@SerializedName("added_date")
String addedDate;

@SerializedName("modified_date")
String modifiedDate;

@SerializedName("archived_date")
String archivedDate;

@SerializedName("status")
String status;

@SerializedName("map_thumbnail")
String mapThumbnail;

@SerializedName("venue_type_id")
int venueTypeId;

public Location(){

}

public Location(int locationId, int companyId, String companyName, String logo, String addressOne, String addressTwo, String addressThree,
                String town, String county, String postcode, String country, Double latitude, Double longitude, String venueType, String type,
                String addedDate, String modifiedDate, String archivedDate, String status, String mapThumbnail, int venueTypeId) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
    this.companyId = companyId;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.logo = logo;
    this.addressOne = addressOne;
    this.addressTwo = addressTwo;
    this.addressThree = addressThree;
    this.town = town;
    this.county = county;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.country = country;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.venueType = venueType;
    this.type = type;
    this.addedDate = addedDate;
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    this.archivedDate = archivedDate;
    this.status = status;
    this.mapThumbnail = mapThumbnail;
    this.venueTypeId = venueTypeId;
}

//Getters and setters
```

/

```
 @GET(NetworkConstants.LOCATIONS_ENDPOINT)
Call<LocationsResponse> getAllLocations(@Header("api-token") String token);
```

I'm using retrofit with Gson for my network call

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string has an invisible non printing character just after the period. Copy and paste to a hex dump and you see:

```
00000000  2d 30 2e e2 80 8e 30 38  36 31 36 37 31 35 37 |-0....086167157|
```

It seems to be a [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)

Solution: fix it in the API. There's no reason clients should filter the input for garbage in numbers.

Comment: better a comment rather than answer?

Comment: @Joni that was a beautiful response to a non constructive comment. Good spot! If I put it in HexEdit get a 0x00 instead of the 0xe2, either way yeah his comms are wrong

Comment: This is awesome, I'd never even heard of invisible characters before, we fixed the data and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Double.parseDouble("-0.086167157") should work!
But there is something wrong with the string in your error message. There seems to be a hidden character, where the point is.